# Flutter: How to get initialized value as the final value if the TextField widget is not changed

Tags: flutter, textfield

This is the code for the TextField. I've initialized it and I want this value to get print when a button is pressed if the text field is not changed.

```dart
Container(
  width: 80,
  child: TextField(
    controller: TextEditingController()..text = '${json['satur']}',
    onChanged: (value) => {
      satur = value,
    },
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
    ),
    cursorColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.orangeAccent, width: 1.0),
        borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.orangeAccent, width: 2.0),
        borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  //flexible
),
```

This is the code for button:

```dart
Material(
  color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
  elevation: 5.0,
  child: MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print("Success");
      print('${satur}');
    },
    minWidth: 100.0,
    height: 42.0,
    child: const Text(
      'Evaluate',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare your `TextEditingController` outside the build method and declare it as a field of the State Class. then when pass it to your `TextField` as the controller. then you can read the current value of the `TextField` using that controller as follows.

```
// inside your State class

TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
//..............

// your text field 
child: TextField(
            controller: textEditingController..text = '${json['satur']}',

//.....................

//inside your onPressed method
onPressed: () {
                        String value = textEditingController.value.text;
                        print("Success");
                        print(value);
                      },
```